# creating retrofit instance failed

Tags: android, retrofit, instance

My app uses an  android service in which 
I create a retrofit instance and make a webservice call, whenever i get a firebase notification.

My app works fine in foreground and background
receives notification and the webservice is also triggered.

But when my app is in kill condition.

I check if the android service is running, if not I start the service and send a broadcast receiver to trigger the webservice call, but i receive  the following error.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.Object retrofit2.Retrofit.create(java.lang.Class)'
>   on a null object reference

Is this because, retrofit instance cannot be created in app kill condition.

how can i fix this?

Thanks in advance

public class FCM_Background extends Service {
    private static String urlString;
    private static String orderBaseUrl, orderUrl, orderMethod, receiveBaseUrl, receiveUrl, receivedMethod;
    private static Context context;

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;
private String orderId;
private ArrayList<Integer> orderid;
DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
private Toast toastMessage;
private String paymentType;
private String orderComment;
private String LogTag = FCM_Background.class.getSimpleName();
private SQLiteHelper helper;
public static SQLiteDatabase db;
private String location_id;
private String state;


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {
    orderid = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            location_id = MyPreferenceManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getData(Common.LOCATION_ID);
            state = intent.getExtras().getString("FROM");

            fetchJsonDataFromRetrofit();

        }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Common.FCM_BROADCAST));

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}


public synchronized void fetchJsonDataFromRetrofit() {
    helper = new SQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext());
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    final ApiInterface listApi = new ApiClient().getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Common.validationToken = MyPreferenceManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getData(Common.AUTH_TOKEN);
    if (null == orderBaseUrl || null == orderUrl) {
        orderBaseUrl = MyPreferenceManager.getInstance(this).getData(Common.DOMAIN_NAME);
        orderUrl = "admin/api/orders";
    }
```

final Call OrderCall = listApi.getOrderDetails(orderBaseUrl, orderUrl, Common.validationToken);

```
    OrderCall.enqueue(new Callback<OrderView>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<OrderView> call, Response<OrderView> response) {


            orderBaseUrl = null;
            orderUrl = null;
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {


                ArrayList<Order> orders = response.body().getOrderList();
                int orderSize = orders != null ? orders.size() : 0;
                String orderType = null;
                String orderCreatedDate = null;

                if (orderSize > 0) {

                    orderDetails(orders, orderType, orderCreatedDate);

                }

            } else {
                ActionOnTokenExpiry(response);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<OrderView> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: if app is in background there is restriction on starting a service in the new android os version. If you need to do something in the background when process is killed you should look at workmanager.

Comment: Can you show some code?